# Checksum process in HDFS /Hadoop

Tags: hdfs

I could not understand how checksum works in HDFS to identify corrupt blocks while file writing reading. can someone explain me in details ?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Apache documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hdfs_design.html#Data+Disk+Failure%2C+Heartbeats+and+Re-Replication) regarding HDFS Architecture.

**Data Integrity**

> It is possible that a block of data fetched from a DataNode arrives corrupted. This corruption can occur because of faults in a storage device, network faults, or buggy software.

It works in below way.

1. The HDFS client software implements checksum checker. When a client creates an HDFS file, it computes a checksum of each block of the file and stores these checksums in a separate hidden file in the same HDFS namespace.
2. When a client retrieves file contents, it verifies that the data it received from each DataNode matches the checksum stored in the associated checksum file.
3. If not, then the client can opt to retrieve that block from another DataNode that has a replica of that block.
4. If checksum of another Data node block matches with checksum of hidden file, system will serve these data blocks.

Have a look at **Robustness** section too. The solution will be incomplete without having look at data replication mechanism.

1. Each DataNode sends a Heartbeat message to the NameNode periodically.
2. A network partition can cause a subset of DataNodes to lose connectivity with the NameNode. The NameNode detects this condition by the absence of a Heartbeat message.
3. The NameNode marks DataNodes without recent Heartbeats as dead and does not forward any new IO requests to them. Any data that was registered to a dead DataNode is not available to HDFS any more.
4. DataNode death may cause the replication factor of some blocks to fall below their specified value. The NameNode constantly tracks which blocks need to be replicated and initiates replication whenever necessary.
5. The necessity for re-replication may arise due to many reasons: a DataNode may become unavailable, a replica may become corrupted, a hard disk on a DataNode may fail, or the replication factor of a file may be increased.

Example of replication scenario:

It depends configuration of the [cluster](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml)

```
dfs.replication

(Assume that it is 3)
```

`dfs.namenode.replication.min` ( Assume that it is 1 )

In case of one Data Node is lost, Name node will recognize that a block is under-replicated. Then Name Node will replicate the data blocks until `dfs.replicaiton` is met.