# Are replicated blocks holds same check-sum?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, checksum

1. Is replicated block holding same **check-sum** value?
2. Can we replicate **check-sum** value?

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33755166/checksum-process-in-hdfs-hadoop

Comment: @BruceWayne: still need clarification on my query even done reading this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33755166/checksum-process-in-hdfs-hadoop. Is replicated block holding same checksum or not?